# Prove that there is exactly one pair of reals $a, b$ such that $x^{2} = x\sin x + \cos x$ for $x=a,b$

Tags: calculus

Some observations.

Let
$$f(x) := x^{2} - x\sin x - \cos x.$$
Then
$$f'(x) = 2x - x\cos x.$$
On setting
$f'(x) := 0,$
I obtain
$$x = 0$$
(because either $x=0$ or $x \neq 0$ and if $x \neq 0$ then $\cos x = 2 > 1.$)
What do I miss so that this proof cannot go on? (Rolle's theorem seems to help?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x > 0, f(0) = - 1 < 0, f(3) > 0, x < 0, f(-4) > 0$. Apply IVT to get at least one zero in each interval. Note that for $x > 0, f'(x) > 0, x < 0, f'(x) < 0$ implies that one and only $1$ zero in each interval, hence exactly $2$ zeroes in $(-\infty, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $f'(x)<0 $ for $x<0$ and $f'(x) >0$ for $x>0$. Note that $f(0) <0$, and
$\lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x) = \infty$.

Hence there is exactly one zero in $(-\infty,0)$ and exactly one zero in $(0,\infty)$.